# Concatenation syntax error using baseurl()

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
echo '<br /><a href=''.base_url().'home/do_logout'>Logout Fool!</a>';
```

What did I missed out in above concatenation?

I got this error

```
Message: syntax error, unexpected ''.base_url()."home/do_logout'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'
```

Comment: you should use and IDE with highlight syntax like netbean

Comment: Hope my answer can help you out! Also if your interested to take a tour about SO see: http://stackoverflow.com/tour (takes less then 1 min and show's how it all works with voting and so on)

Comment: You need to understand also, the difference in using double quotes vs single quotes. Double quotes PHP will try to parse variables, single it will not.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
echo "<br /><a href='" . base_url() . "home/do_logout'>Logout Fool!</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using mixed mode processing looks cleaner some of the time - and easier to maintain. Close and reopen your php tags when you want to switch to just html

```
<br>
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/do_logout">Logout Fool!</a>
```